# Can I make the Witcher 3's inventory faster?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing *The Witcher 3* on the **PS4**, with all addons and expansions.

When I want to use the inventory or put items in my stash, the transfer takes a huge amount of time. Sometimes between 10 and 20 seconds per item to transfer. Multiply this by the number of items anyone wants to transfer, and it soons become a nightmare that we face.

How come the inventory is so slow? Can its speed be improved?

Comment: Your game is being saved every time you transfer something into your stash I'm guessing.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that you had the same problem I remember having. If so, then it's because your stash - the chest that sits in on the ground floor of the hotel in Novigrad, the inn in Skellige, your home in Corvo Bianco - has gotten quite loaded. It's noticeable if you have a habit of saving one of each type of witcher armor, collecting curios from various quests, and so on.

I don't know why it isn't optimized for better access. The only thing I could do to reduce the access time on it was to empty out things I concluded I would never look at again, such as old notes and letters, low level swords and armor I thought were interesting at the time, and so on.